# Task doesn't work out in ASP.NET MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, task-parallel-library

I want to do some work asyncroniously in my web app.
I do this in such a way:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    model.PhoneNumber = MakePhoneNumberStandard(model.PhoneNumber);
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.PhoneNumber, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            {
                using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    var activated = DbHelper.Activated(db, model.PhoneNumber);

                    if (activated)
                    {
                        var browser = Request["browser"];
                        var os = Request["os"];
                        var ip = Request["ip"];

                        LoginVerificationModel data = new LoginVerificationModel()
                        {
                            DbContext = db,
                            PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber,
                            Browser = browser,
                            Os = os,
                            Ip = ip,
                            AllocatedSeconds = AllocatedSecondsForLogin,
                            LoginTime = DateTime.UtcNow
                        };  

                        Task task = new Task(DbHelper.VerifyLoginAsyncWrap, data);
                        task.Start();                               

                        return View();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Activation");
                    }
                }
            }
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

I want to get a web page, and the server to do some else work in background at that time.

When I perform Login method, the task runs, but it doesn't perform all the work, as if its thread is stopped in the middle.

Does it work this way?

Comment: You are blocking the thread with a synchronous call in n asynchronous method. I think you need to add "Async Await" before calling task.Start if you have the background work in the part that you marked as //some work

Comment: See my blog post on [ASP.NET background tasks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way if you "want to get a web page, and the server to do some else work in background at that time".

Have an index method to return your view, and at document.ready() of the page you can have an ajax call to your specific controller method.

Also, if you use async method, you should await the async call that you make in your controller to get the return value of the call.

Comment: There's an "await" in the code above which awaits signing in. I used AJAX, but is this the only way? What if it could be turned off in browser settings?

Comment: I am unable to find that in your question.

Comment: Code execution can't go beyond the await statement untill it returns. Which view you want to return?